# Wicket logging configuration

Tags: logging, configuration, log4j, wicket

I have a Wicket 1.4.17 app in a standalone app in embedded Jetty 6.1.26.
My application uses `log4j` over `slf4j`.

My app consists of two JARs, core and web modules.
I have same `log4j.properties` in both - by which I tried to exclude a possibility of some classloader not picking up .properties from non-web JAR.

For my classes, the log4j configuration works - e.g. the messages are on a single line.
However, for Wicket, it seems to use some default.

How can I unify logging config?

BTW Jetty uses `java.util.logging`.

Thanks,
Ondra

Comment: Wicket uses SLF4J API (slf4j-api.jar). It is up to your application to provide SLF4J implementation (e.g. slf4j-log4j.jar + log4j.jar).

Comment: Thanks, reworded to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it stopped behaving so after I cleaned up dependencies a bit.
http://code.google.com/p/ondrazizka/source/detail?r=187#

I removed pljFilter, which brought in commons-logging, so most probably that was causing problems. Can't explain, I'm not keen on logging config.

Answer (score 0):

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit

Well, try to use `2` from here:

> Set the resource string variable to
>   the value of the log4j.configuration
>   system property. The preferred way to
>   specify the default initialization
>   file is through the
>   log4j.configuration system property.
>   In case the system property
>   log4j.configuration is not defined,
>   then set the string variable resource
>   to its default value
>   "log4j.properties".